# Preventing socket.join("room") client-side, listening for private room leaving

Tags: javascript, websocket, node.js

i'm developing an application with Socket.IO that needs to authenticate if user can join a room.

Client side:

```
var socket = io('http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];?>:3000');
socket.on('connect', function() {
    var req = [current_user_id,secret_hash];
    socket.emit('join', req);
});
```

Server listens on join requests of clients, gets access to a MySQL database and evaluates if user can join or not the requested hash channel:

```
        ...
        if (rows.length == 1) {
            socket.join(request[1]); //join on channel ID which is request[1] cell of array
        }
        //if not authorized, does not allow joining.
        ...
```

I've got two questions:

1) I don't want to allow client side direct joning of channel. Clients must not be able to launch socket.join("room"). How can i block those requests? Server is the only one that cares about assigning rooms.

2) Is there a way to listen for event "user leaves his private channel id"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The client-side socket.io library does not have the ability to `.join()` a room.  That ability is only in the server-side library (because that's where the rooms are maintained) and thus the only place it can actually be processed.

So, the only way to join a room is to make your own message for a join request from client to server and process that message on the server on behalf of a given client which enables you to do any sort of checking you want before any client can join a particular room.  As such, you should be safe the way you're already doing it.

---

Similarly, there are only two ways that a client leaves a room.  The first is when you process your own message and call `.leave()` server-side so you can certainly monitor any time that happens since it's your own server-side code calling `.leave()`.  The other way a client leaves a room is when the client disconnects and you can also monitor for disconnects in the server.  Like with `.join()`, the client cannot call `.leave()` directly so you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Nice, i did not notice that .join() was only server side. However, i need to perform actions when user leaves his private channel. Listening on io.on(disconnect) would not be enough, i need some event on leaving of any room.

Comment: @Mario90 - client-side event or server-side event upon leaving a room?

Comment: Server side event, binded on any room leaved, in my case user's private room.

Comment: @Mario90 - as described in my answer, you can listen for disconnect events and just change any place in your server-side code that does a `.leave()` to notify your server code that one is leaving a room when it does the `.leave()`.  Since all the server-side code is under your control, this should be something you can do.  If you really want to automate this, then you could override the `.leave()` method so that it would do the `.leave()` and then notify you.  Or, you could create your own `.leaveNotify()` method and replace all occurrences of `.leave()` in your own code with `.leaveNotify()`.

Comment: Could you please do a code example? Thanks.

Comment: @Mario90 - what part don't you understand?

Comment: I understood. I should, in my case, listen disconnect even in general, take the socket object of the disconnected client and perform operations on rooms of the socket, right?